# Spacing in python string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, spacing

Can't seem to figure out what's going on with my spacing in python. I'm trying to get it to print this:

```
Two Vertical Lines, height=3; width=3:
* *
* *
* *

Two Vertical Lines, height=4; width=5:
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *

Two Vertical Lines, height=5; width=2:
**
**
**
**
**
```

but with this code:

```
def two_vertical_lines (height, width):
    for x in range (0, height):
        if width > 2:
            new_width = width - 2 
            mult2 = " " * new_width
            print ("*",mult2,"*", "\n", end='')
        else:
             print ("**", "\n", end='')
    return
```

For some reason, my program is returning:

```
Two Vertical Lines, height=3; width=3:
*  * 
*  * 
*  * 

Two Vertical Lines, height=4; width=5:
*  * 
*  * 
*  * 
*  * 

Two Vertical Lines, height=5; width=2:
** 
** 
** 
** 
**
```

(notice the difference in spacing/width between the two vertical lines, even though my variable new_width should technically be 1 space)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code... What is displayed in my PyCharm is perfectly fine... maybe you want to figure out the way you print them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `print()` outputs its arguments separated with a single ' ' (space).  However, this can be changed with the `sep` parameter.  Just use `sep=''` like below:

```
def two_vertical_lines (height, width):
    for x in range (0, height):
        if width > 2:
            new_width = width - 2 
            mult2 = " " * new_width
            print ("*", mult2, "*", sep='')  # <-- change
        else:
             print ("**", "\n", end='')
    return
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `print`, all the parameters passed to it will be printed with a space between them.

```
>>> print('a', 'b')
a b
```

To fix this, you can create a single string and print it, like this

```
print ("*{}*\n".format(mult2), end='')
```

In fact, instead of explicitly adding `\n` in the string, you can let `print` function take care of it, like this

```
print ("*{}*".format(mult2))
```

---

Another improvement could be, you don't have to special case, `width <= 2` cases, because string multiplication with zero or negative integers will result in empty strings only.

```
>>> '*' * -1
''
>>> '*' * 0
''
```

So you can simply write

```
def two_vertical_lines(height, width):
    for x in range(height):
        print("*{}*".format(" " * (width - 2)))
```